# routing in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.3, cakephp-routing

I'm working on CakePHP 3.3

I have some dashboard controllers which are named like

```
DashboardUsersController.php, 
DashboardBusinessesController.php,
DashboardCustomersController.php, 
etc
```

I want to map urls like

```
http://example.com/dashboard/users/view/param1/param2
```

And this will call `DashboardUsersController.php` class and `view` function with `param1` and `param2` as parameters.

In short I want to change url `http://example.com/dashboard-users/view/param` to `http://example.com/dashboard/users/view/param`

this type of mapping will be done only if dashboard is present after domain, otherwise it will work as default like on accessing `http://example.com/users/view/param1` will call `UsersController.php`

**What I have done till now?**

Since, I'm new to CakePHP and routing, I have no idea where to start from and therefore have done nothing till now. I need your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you needed is prefix. Bake your controller model with prefix dashboard .

Use this in you **routes.php**

```
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;

Router::prefix('dashboard', function ($routes) {
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/dashboard
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

And remove that dashboard part from controllers or remove dashboard from your table name and rebake everything with --prefix .

> bin/cake bake all --prefix dashboard

These links will help you

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html

Comment: Am glad to help yu :)

Comment: There is an issue. I have two `UsersController.php` classes each in `/src/controller/Dashboard/` prefix and in `/src/controller/`. I'm using `/src/controller/UsersController.php` to login in `authComponent` but on trying to access unautherised page in `dashboard` prefix. It is redirecting to `/src/controller/dashboard/users/login` instead of `/src/controller/users/login`

Comment: got it working... added `'prefix' => false` in `authComponent`

Comment: Was about to comment d same